# Compute minimum dot product c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, dot-product

I am trying to compute the minimum dot product for two arrays/vectors. Below are the details:

**Problem:** given two sequences a1, a2, . . . , and b1, b2, . . . , bn, find a permutation π of the second sequence such that the dot product of a1, a2, . . . , an and bπ1, bπ2, . . . , bπn is minimum.

My logic is working fine but when i try for input as below , its failing due to integer overflow. What data types i shall use for accommodating my condition 1 ≤ n ≤ 10^3; −10^5 ≤ ai, bi ≤ 10^5 for all 1 ≤ i ≤ n

1

99999

99999

The out put for the above scenario should be 9999800001 , but i am getting 1409865409

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

using std::vector;

int64_t min_dot_product(int n, vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
    int64_t result = 0;
    if (n != 0)
    {
        std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
        std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());
        std::reverse(a.begin(), a.end());

        /*for (long long int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result += a[i] * b[n - 1 - i];
        }*/

        result = std::inner_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n), b(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> b[i];
    }
    std::cout << min_dot_product(n, a, b) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You're not supposed to change the order of a, only b.

Comment: Also, `std::next_permutation` may be of interest to you.

Comment: No it works even if i change the order of a as well, i have tested the same.

Comment: Actually, you're right. Any change in a's order is the same as a change in the resulting b if a is unchanged.

Comment: I am trying to learn if there is anything wrong in the question i have asked ? as its down voted by some one. Any input is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make following changes:

1. Replace `vector<int>` by `vector<int64_t>` to store number in 64 bit integer.
2. Use `result = std::inner_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0LL);`
   (`0LL` suggest that result is `int64_t`)

The problem is that you are storing it in `int32_t` and so multiplication overflows.

Comment: Given the range of the numbers in each vector, there is no need to replace `vector<int>` by `vector<int64_t>`. An `int32_t` will do.

Comment: For some reason Int32 isn't working. Int64_t made it work.  and that 0LL is the main thing i missed before when i changed to Int64_t. Thank you very much !

Comment: @StoryTeller, `int32_t` won't work in our case. Because in library implementation of `std::inner_product`, it multiplies the values without casting it into datatype of result. So, `int32_t` will be multiplied and results overflows.

Comment: You are quite mistaken on this. The return type of inner_product is the same as the initial value passed to it. And the requirement on the operators is such that the return value from them can be converted to the return type. Long story short, unless an implicit conversion from `int32_t` to `int64_t` fails, you don't have to needlessly expand your vectors.

Comment: @StoryTeller, Imagine you're inner-summing vectors of Math vectors, where you overloaded * to do a dot product. If the implementation returns `a1*b1 + a2*b2 + ...`, everything is good and it returns a scalar. However, if it tries to convert before multiplying (`R(a1)*R(b1) + ...`), it's going to fail because of the lack of conversion between your Math vector and a scalar. I don't see the standard imposing that the multiplication operands are pre-converted to the result type, just that the overall result is, in order for more genericity.

Comment: @StoryTeller, `int32_t` will not be promoted to `int64_t` before multiplication. The formula is `res = res + a*b` where a,b are `int32_t`. The result `a*b` will be promoted to `int64_t`.

Comment: @chris, yes I can imagine a case where a conversion fails. Hence my carefully stated comment. However, the standard mandates the conversion holds if you expect your code to compile, so this is a moot point.

Comment: @StoryTeller, "the requirement on the operators is such that the return value from them can be converted to the return type" - My example satisfies this. The scalar returned from multiplying two Math vectors is convertible to whatever scalar return type you expect from doing an inner product (oops, said inner sum last time) on a bunch of Math vectors given dot products for multiplication.

Comment: @chris, and your code will rightfully build. The second implementation will fail to build your code (which satisfies all base requirements). So I'd say it's non-standard compliant, and therefore I don't expect to see it.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I gave in and opened up the draft standard. *Computes its result by initializing the accumulator `acc` with the initial value `init` and
then modifying it with `acc = acc + (*i1) * (*i2)`*

Comment: @chris, that's what I remembered. And it also validates Rishit's point. I was mistaken thinking it wouldn't overflow. I hoped integer promotion can save us, but alas.

Comment: @StoryTeller, Interestingly, promotion would if we had a data type smaller than `int`, such as `short` (assuming they're not the same size on that implementation). In that case, the `short`s would be promoted to `int`s before being multiplied just because of the way the language is with integral operators.

Comment: @chris, with 16-bit shorts and 32-bit ints, short can hold values of up to 10⁵, yet multiplying 10⁵*10⁵ would overflow despite operands being promoted to ints. :)

Comment: @bipll, Yeah, I was speaking in a more general sense there.